# AS3 un-multiply alpha when reading bitmap data from byteArray

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm trying to read in a bitmap from a ByteArray and I'm using:

```
bitmapData = new BitmapData(width, height, transparent);
bitmapData.setPixels(new Rectangle(0, 0, width, height), byteArray);
```

However, the bitmap that I'm reading has pre-multiplied alpha and using this method ends up with grey pixels in some of the semi-transparent areas.

Is there a way I can un-multiply the source in code? or perhaps a different way to load in the ByteArray to get around this?

Comment: what is the value of the var "transparent"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a shader filter, for example, to un-multiply alpha. Say like this one:

```
kernel unmultiply_alpha
<   namespace : "Your Namespace";
    vendor : "Your Vendor";
    version : 1;
>
{
    input image4 src;
    output pixel4 dst;

    void
    evaluatePixel()
    {
        pixel4 samp = sampleNearest(src,outCoord());
        if (samp.a>0.1) {
            samp.r=samp.r/samp.a;
            samp.g=samp.g/samp.a;
            samp.b=samp.b/samp.a;
        }
        dst=samp;
    }
}
```

Just set a correct threshold for alpha in code. Here alpha is in interval 0..1, so use proper value.
Yes, to apply filter, you first import a PBJ of the shader (to make a PBJ, use Pixel Bender) as a ByteArray in your code, then use:

```
var shader:Shader=new Shader(new ImportedShader() as ByteArray);
var filter:ShaderFilter=new ShaderFilter(shader);
bitmapData.applyFilter(bitmapData,bitmapData.rect,new Point(),filter);
```